# How can I redirect the output of screen to a file?

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to capture data from a Serial Port by opening 'screen' from the terminal. It works, I see the data coming but I can't figure out how to save it to a file.

I tried to redirect the output of screen by adding `> file.txt` to the command line that opens screen, something like this:

```
screen /dev/tty.Airconsole-1 > file.txt
```

But it didn't work, it creates an empty file but I still see the data on the screen window.

Ideally I would like to redirect to both, I mean keep it in the window and at the same time feeding the file, probably by using the tee command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found possible answer at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208001/save-screen-program-output-to-a-file):

Have you tried:

```
screen -L /dev/tty.Airconsole-1 > file.txt
```

Comment: No, I haven't tried the log option. I was looking to redirect the output as it comes, but will try it and will try the last answer in the link you sent me, the one with script. Thanks.

Comment: Tried the linked answer, the one with script and works precisely as expected. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can get screen log with interactive command "Control-a H" on screen command. It create a log file as "screenlog.n" on your user directory such as "/Users/xxxx".
Please see below link:
https://ss64.com/osx/screen.html